# Map <C-S-A-hjkl> to Arrow Keys with XKB Map

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I'm trying to also have access to my arrow keys from the default Vim <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> seems to be a rare key combo, I was thinking about using that.

How would I do that using `setxkbmap` (or another equivalent tool)?

Answer (score 1):

using a similar setup with caps+hjkl via xkb. i'm sure you can adapt it easily. caps is set as level5 modifier.

**1. put `xkb_symbols "vim"` in `~/.config/xkb/symbols/vim-keys`**

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "vim"  {
  name[Group1]= "L5: vim arrow keys";
  key <AC06> {
    type = "EIGHT_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [          h,          H,     ugrave,     Ugrave,       Left,       Left,       Left,       Left ]
  };
  key <AC07> {
    type = "EIGHT_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [          j,          J,     uacute,     Uacute,       Down,       Down,       Down,       Down ]
  };
  key <AC08> {
    type = "EIGHT_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [          k,          K,      U0133,      U0132,         Up,         Up,         Up,         Up ]
  };
  key <AC09> {
    type = "EIGHT_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [          l,          L,     oslash,     Oslash,      Right,      Right,      Right,      Right ]
  };
  include "level5(caps_switch)"
};
```

**2. add level5 group `rules/evdev.xml`**

copy `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` to `~/.config/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` and add

```
    <group allowMultipleSelection="true">
      <configItem>
        <name>L5</name>
        <description>Level5 keys</description>
      </configItem>
      <option>
        <configItem>
          <name>l5:vim</name>
          <description>vim: hjkl arrows</description>
        </configItem>
      </option>
    </group>
```

**3. map rules to symbols in `rules/evdev`**

copy `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` to `~/.config/xkb/rules/evdev` and add

```
l5:vim               = +l5(vim)`
```

**4. activate**

e.g. in gnome-settings or via

```
$ setxkbmap us -option l5:vim
```

now you can press caps+hjkl for arrow keys, works nicely on my laptops without a proper qmk keyboard.

**note:** quickly copy pasted this from my own setup, renamed a bit, hope i didnt miss anything and it helps you!

Comment: I, as well as many Vim users, use CapsLock as Esc actually. Won't this conflict with it? This looks way more complicated than I expected too.

Comment: yes, this will conflict with caps:escape. for me it's a workaround for not having qmk on laptops and that's ok. on qmk i have caps to be esc on tap, mod on hold, love that.

you could use e.g. right-alt as level3 mod and add the keys there, which would be the 3rd/4th columns.